# How to Record or Clip Video from a video file Using Qt?

Tags: qt, video-processing, qt5

I am using visual studio 2010 integrated with Qt5.0.1.

I want to record or clip a video from a video file.

I used QMediarecorder but cannot able to record the video. Below is the snippet I am using.

Any solution will be helpful.

```
QMediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
mediaPlayer.setmedia("c:\\sample.avi");
QVideoWidget videoWidget;
mediaPlayer.setVideoOutput(&videoWidget);
mediaPlayer.play();

QMediaRecorder *mediaRecorder = new QMediaRecorder(&mediaPlayer);
QVideoEncoderSettings *videosettings = new QVideoEncoderSettings;

videosettings->setResolution(1280,720);
videosettings->setQuality(QMultimedia::VeryHighQuality);
videosettings->setFrameRate(25.0);
videosettings->setCodec("H.264Video");
mediaRecorder->setVideoSettings(settings);
QString file = "C:\\record.avi";
QFile file1(file);
file1.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
mediaRecorder->setContainerFormat("avi");
mediaRecorder->setOutputLocation(QUrl::fromLocalFile(file));
mediaRecorder->record();
```

after some seconds in another function i will call
       mediaRecorder->stop();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `mediaRecorder->setVideoSettings`, set it to `videosettings`. You don't have a variable `settings`.